# Dynamic value of rotation in folium beautify icon

Tags: python, css, flask, folium

```
 for lat,long,alt,angle, in zip(df_plane["Lat"], df_plane["Long"], df_plane["Alt"], df_plane["Angle"]):

 fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lat, long], 
                               icon=plugins.BeautifyIcon(icon='plane',
                                            border_color='transparent',
                                            background_color='transparent',
                                            border_width=1,
                                            text_color='#003EFF',
                                            inner_icon_style='margin:0px;font-size:2em;-webkit-transform: rotate(angle);-moz-transform: rotate(angle);-ms-transform: rotate(angle);-o-transform: rotate(angle);transform: rotate(angle);')))
```

The angle variable is not working in the `inner_icon_style`. I want to use angle variable as dynamic value so each icon rotate different. Thank you.

Comment: What about `inner_icon_style='margin:0px;font-size:2em;-webkit-transform: rotate({0});-moz-transform: rotate({0});-ms-transform: rotate({0});-o-transform: rotate({0});transform: rotate({0});'.format(angle)))`

Answer (score 1):

the following worked for me (notice the addition of "deg" in the rotate function to specify the unit, and that's what made it work) :

```
m.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lat, long], 
                           icon=plugins.BeautifyIcon(icon='plane',
                                        border_color='transparent',
                                        background_color='transparent',
                                        border_width=1,
                                        text_color='#003EFF',
                                        inner_icon_style='margin:0px;font-size:2em;transform: rotate({0}deg);'.format(angle))))
```